# HTML/CSS Menu Active Link Background Not Aligned

Tags: html, css

I have a HTML menu that uses a class to show which page is currently active within the website.

```
<div id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li class="activelink"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="early.html">Growing Up and School</a></li>
        <li><a href="career.html">Films</a></li>
        <li><a href="jamesbond.html">James Bond</a></li>
        <li><a href="gallery.html">Pictures</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

When I've been designing the menu, I have used Firefox to preview the local files and it looked fine. However, when I viewed the menu in Chrome and IE, the background that shows which menu item is active is well out of line vertically within the menu.

Please see http://jsfiddle.net/C9mZG/

In fact, when I've copied the code to that jsfiddle and viewed it in Firefox, the same problem as Chrome and IE shows up but for some reason, the menu on my local file still looks absolutely fine. I'm guessing that my menu is styled wrong but I just can't work it out. Basically the darker red background that shows the current link should be in line vertically with the lighter red menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `#menu` is 30px tall while your `ul` is 40px tall. Now, the fact is that all your `li` elements have the same height and overflow from your `ul`. You just don't notice it because they have a transparent background.

I've added some background color so you can better visualize:

```
li {background: rgba(0,64,128,0.5);}
```

You can see it here: http://jsfiddle.net/C9mZG/4/

One possible solution would be to make your `#menu` taller. Alternatively, you could reduce the padding on your `li` elements.

BTW: you'll also notice that your last `li` goes on another line because of the width of your `#menu`, breaking your layout.

Comment: Thank you. I've now got the menu perfect on jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/C9mZG/22/

But...when I move this to the rest of my content, the menu displays like this - http://jsfiddle.net/Y8nfG/

Comment: I'm not gonna troubleshoot your whole stylesheet. Try removing everything, then add a few rules at a time to see what makes or breaks your design. Good luck.

Comment: Got it, thank you! It was something to do with setting body font-size to 62.5% to work with ems.

Answer (score 1):

Apply a css reset to the padding and margin

```
*{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
```

At the beginning of your css

http://jsfiddle.net/C9mZG/3/